# set some rule to groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I need to set some rule to groupby in pandas. I hope I can ignore the rows if ['keep'] column have "dup by" before I groupby the datetime.

There is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv",delimiter='|')

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'],errors = 'coerce')
most_recent_date = df.groupby(df['VIP_ID'])['datetime'].max()
most_recent_date= most_recent_date.rename("most_recent_date")
df = df.join(most_recent_date, on="VIP_ID")

df['both'] = np.where(
       ((df['keep'] == 'same tier')&(dup == 'yes')),
          df['VIP_ID']+df['datetime'].astype(str),
         df['ID']
)
df['keep'] = np.where(
    df['keep'] != 'same tier',df['keep'],
    (np.where(
         df['most_recent_date'] == df['datetime'],
         'yes',
         'dup by ' + df['VIP_ID'].astype(str)))
)



df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['both'], keep = False),'keep'] = 'same time'
df = df.drop(columns = ['both','most_recent_date'])
print(df)
```

And this code make all keep column become 'dup by'.

example csv:

```
ID|VIP_ID|TIER|datatime|keep
1|F08210020403|GO|2014-05-17 00:00:00|same tier
2|F08210020403|GO|2014-04-18 00:00:00|same tier
3|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
4|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
5|F08210020403|FO|2016-09-18 00:00:00|dup by F08210020403
6|F08210020403|FO|2016-05-10 00:00:00|dup by F08210020403
7|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
8|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
```

Because 2016-05-10 00:00:00 is the max datetime by F08210020403, all keep columns will show dup by F08210020403.I hope I can set some rules about if keep contain 'dup', ignore this row. After than
groupby remain rows.

This is my output:

```
1|F08210020403|GO|2014-05-17 00:00:00|dup by F08210020403
2|F08210020403|GO|2014-04-18 00:00:00|dup by F08210020403
3|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
4|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
5|F08210020403|FO|2016-09-18 00:00:00|dup by F08210020403
6|F08210020403|FO|2016-05-10 00:00:00|dup by F08210020403
7|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
8|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
```

expect output:

```
1|F08210020403|GO|2014-05-17 00:00:00|yes
2|F08210020403|GO|2014-04-18 00:00:00|dup by F08210020403
3|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
4|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
5|F08210020403|FO|2016-09-18 00:00:00|dup by F08210020403
6|F08210020403|FO|2016-05-10 00:00:00|dup by F08210020403
7|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
8|F08210020403|FO||dup by F08210020403
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

```
c=df['keep'].str.contains('dup by')
#created a condition which check if 'keep' column contains 'dup by' or not
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'],errors = 'coerce')
most_recent_date = df[~c].groupby(df['VIP_ID'])['datetime'].max()
#excluded those rows in groupby where 'keep' contains 'dup by'
df['most_recent_date']=df['VIP_ID'].map(most_recent_date)
df['both'] = np.where((df['keep'] == 'same tier') & c,df['VIP_ID']+df['datetime'].astype(str),df['ID'])
df['keep'] = np.where(
    df['keep'] != 'same tier',df['keep'],
    (np.where(
         df['most_recent_date'] == df['datetime'],
         'yes',
         'dup by ' + df['VIP_ID'].astype(str)))
)
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['both'], keep = False),'keep'] = 'same time'
df = df.drop(columns = ['both','most_recent_date'])
```